# Sorting list or getAll in Grails

Tags: grails, groovy

I wanted to implement a default sort order in my domain class and immediately found it didn't work with the `getAll` method.  No biggie, I just used `list` instead. The thing is that the default sort order in a domain class does not allow you specify multiple sort fields ([as seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4882992/grails-mapping-sort-on-multiple-fields-groovy-sort-on-multiple-map-entries)).

My goal is to sort all `Foo` objects first by the name of their `Bar` object, then by their own name.

```
class Foo {
    String name
    String Bar
}

class Bar {
    String name
}
```

How can I implement this in the domain class so I don't have to specify a long/nasty comparator every time I call `.list()`?

One of my attempts:

```
static Comparator getComparator() { 
    def c = { a, b -> 
    def result = a.bar.name.compareTo( b.bar.name ); 
        if ( result == 0 ) {
            result = a.name.compareTo( b.name );
        }
    }
    return c as Comparator
}
```

Then I could just call `Foo.list(Foo.getComparator())`... if I could get it to work.

**Update:**

I think I am really close here, just having trouble with implementing two comparisons in the same sort closure.

```
Foo.list().sort{ a, b ->
    def result = a.bar.name <=> b.bar.name;
    // Things mess up when I put this if statement in.
    if( result == 0 ) {
        a.name <=> b.name
    }
}
```

**Disco!**

```
class Foo { // My domain class
    // ...

    static Comparator getComparator() {
        def c =[
            compare: { a, b ->
                def result = a.bar.name <=> b.bar.name;
                if( result == 0 ) {
                    result = a.name <=> b.name
                }
                return result
            }
        ] as Comparator
    }

    // ...
}
```

And implemented like this in my controller:

```
Foo.list().sort( Foo.getComparator() )
```

**PS:**

The above works, but Jeff Storey posted some code in his answer after I discoed, and his code works and is much nicer than mine so use it :)

Comment: Looks like you found your answer, FYI using `a.bar.name <=> b.bar.name ?: a.name <=> b.name` is idiomatic groovy situations with fallback comparison keys.  Also, since these are domain objects, I'd suggest doing your sorting in the DB if you can.  Unless the set of them is really small, doing it in groovy will likely be orders of magnitude slower.

Comment: Doing it in the database means HQL via the executeQuery method correct?

Comment: Yes, that's how I'd do it.  You could probably also use criteria for this, but I find criteria a lot more awkward to write than HQL which is very close to SQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case, would it make sense to have `Foo` implement `Comparable` and the implementation could do the comparison as you described? Then when you sort the objects in a list, because they are `Comparable`, they will sort properly.

If it does not make sense for you to implement `Comparable` though, you will need to specify a comparator to sort by.

Here's some sample code based on your comments:

edit:

```
class Person implements Comparable<Person> {

   String firstName
   String lastName

   int compareTo(Person other) {
       int lastNameCompare = lastName <=> other.lastName
       return lastNameCompare != 0 ? lastNameCompare : firstName <=> other.firstName
   }

   String toString() {
     "${lastName},${firstName}"
   }
}

def people = [new Person(firstName:"John",lastName:"Smith"), new Person(firstName:"Bill",lastName:"Jones"), new Person(firstName:"Adam",lastName:"Smith")]
println "unsorted = ${people}"
println "sorted = ${people.sort()}"
```

This prints:

```
unsorted = [Smith,John, Jones,Bill, Smith,Adam]
sorted = [Jones,Bill, Smith,Adam, Smith,John]
```

Comment: If I implement the Comparable interface how do I make Grails use it for sorting?  I know how to compare two object `foo1.compareTo(foo2)` but I need to implement this on a list of objects.

Comment: list.sort() http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#sort()

Comment: Right, I don't think implementing the comparable interface is my issue (though I did try it as you can see by the use of `compareTo` in "One of my attempts" in my question).  I can already do a decent comparison with a closure with `a.bar.name <=> b.bar.name`.  I think most my issues are coming from ordering by two fields at the same time. An easier example to understand, imagine ordering first by last name, then by first name. Thus if there were two people with the last name `Smith` `Adam Smith` would come before `John Smith`.

Comment: Ah, if your code is correct then THAT is what I was looking for. I didn't realize simply calling `.sort()` after you had implemented the `compareTo()` method would actually use the `compareTo()` method.  I'll give this a shot as it is much cleaner than my solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To further simplify the above post (I would have commented on it but I don't have the rep yet), you can chain the groovy compare operators using the elvis operator:

```
class Person implements Comparable<Person> {

    String firstName
    String lastName

    int compareTo(Person other) {
        return lastName <=> other.lastName ?: firstName <=> other.firstName
    }

    String toString() {
        "${lastName},${firstName}"
    }
}

def people = [new Person(firstName:"John",lastName:"Smith"), new Person(firstName:"Bill",lastName:"Jones"), new     Person(firstName:"Adam",lastName:"Smith")]
println "unsorted = ${people}"
println "sorted = ${people.sort()}"
```

This will give you the same result because 0 is considered false in groovy's eyes, which will make it look at the next conditional in the chain.