# Groovy list sort on two criteria

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a list of objects which are all the same type and have two properties a 'uniqueId', and a 'secondaryId'. I want to sort this list first by 'uniqueId' and then by 'secondaryId' for each uniqueId so that this list:

UniqueID/SecondaryID
5/3
2/6
5/8
2/5

once sorted will look like:
2/5
2/6
5/3
5/8

I can't seem to get the syntax quite right:

```
return searchResults.sort{[it.uniqueId, it.secondaryId]}
```

is what I am trying to start with but that didn't work.

Comment: http://www.intelligrape.com/blog/2012/08/10/groovier-way-of-sorting-over-multiple-fields-in-a-list-of-maps-in-groovy/ which led to https://gist.github.com/timyates/3314416

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [the elvis operator](http://www.intelligrape.com/blog/2012/08/10/groovier-way-of-sorting-over-multiple-fields-in-a-list-of-maps-in-groovy/) for a [second sorting criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4882992/grails-mapping-sort-on-multiple-fields-groovy-sort-on-multiple-map-entries):

```
map = [[u:5, s:3],
 [u:2, s:6],
 [u:5, s:8],
 [u:2, s:5]]

sort = { m ->
  m.sort { e1, e2 -> 
    e1.u <=> e2.u ?: e1.s <=> e2.s 
  } 
}

assert sort(map) == [[u:2, s:5], 
 [u:2, s:6], 
 [u:5, s:3], 
 [u:5, s:8]]
```