# can we use two criterias in sort

Tags: sorting, collections, groovy

I have been using the following code for sorting a domain's results

> vpisort.sort{it.price}

I was wondering If i could use something like

> vpisort.sort{it.price-it?.discount}

Comment: Do you need it to make on query level, or against current results (mean existing list)? If second, then your example must works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found [this](http://kousenit.wordpress.com/2012/01/13/elvis-carried-away-by-spaceships/) post. You can try using this in your case:

```
vpisort.sort { a, b -> a.price <=> b.price ?: a?.discount <=> b?.discount }
```

It comapres price first and then, only if a and b are equal by price and result is zero, using Elvis operator it compares a and by by discount.

Answer (score 1):

hm. This is not a grails, but a groovy question. With this in mind, the solution is simple:

open the groovy console and give your line a try. Or check out these examples:

http://groovy.codehaus.org/JN1015-Collections

there is also another question like this one on SO:

[Groovy list.sort by first, second then third elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467641/groovy-list-sort-by-first-second-then-third-elements)

hope that helps!

**Update:** If you want to have a default sort order for your domain class, take a look at this GORM feature: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#ormdsl (5.5.3 Default Sort Order)